# Programmatically generated buttons can't be pressed when the app is restarted

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, button

I have programmatically generated a series of buttons in my app, and they work perfectly when they are pressed. Then I stored in memory the number of the buttons and, when I restart the app, the buttons are regenerated exactly as they were before, and yet they can't be pressed.
The method "deletebtn" prints "pressed" when the button is pressed, but it doesn't.
I've even tried to add to the properties of the programmatically generated button "buttonName.userInteractionEnabled = true", but nothing changes.

This are the properties of the button, and that's also the code I have on the viewdidload, that recreates as much buttons as the number of them that I have stored in memory:

```
let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10, CGFloat(60*a), ScreenWidth - 20 , 50))    
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * btn.bounds.size.height
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
btn.setTitle(ArrayService[(index)], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("deletebtn:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
btn.tag = a //an int variable that is increased each time i create a neew button
btn.userInteractionEnabled = true
self.ScrollPwd.addSubview(btn)
```

And here is the method deletebtn:

```
func deletebtn(sender:UIButton){
        print("pressed")
}
```

The scrollView is where I put my buttons. I've tried adding "ScrollPwd.userInteractionEnabled = true", and yet I can just scroll through the buttons, but I can't press them.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Don't save the button. Save only its properties and recreate them when needed

Comment: Without some code - at the very least, what is being executed when restarting your app - it is **impossible** to know how to help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Much better. Now, do you know for a fact that **deletebtn()** is not being executed? If so, how? Could you show that code? Also, where is the code you have posted that creates these buttons?

Comment: try this self.ScrollPwd.clipsToBounds = YES after this, check if buttons are visible or not?

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: How do you create `ScrollPwd`?  Does it have user interaction enabled.

Comment: It is just a scrollView where I put the buttons. I have not written anywhere userInteractionEnabled = true, but I can scroll through the buttons, I just can't press them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. It's pretty awkward actually: what happens it's just that when you restart the app the logs don't appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think the big problem was how you are defining the action.  Here's an updated version (in Swift 3)

```
let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 60 * indexButton, width: screenWidth - 20, height: 50))
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * btn.bounds.size.height
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
btn.setTitle(arrayService[indexButton], for: .normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.deletebtn), for: .touchUpInside)

btn.tag = indexButton
self.scrollPwd.addSubview(btn)
```

I couldn't help changing (fixing) some of your variable names.  You should try to avoid capitalizing variable names, because that's reserved for class names - so `ScreenWidth` should really be `screenWidth`, and when you already have a variable `index`, you don't need an identical, randomly named variable `a` to hold the same information.  Also, `indexButton` tells us what the index is used for

Comment: The line "btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.deletebtn), for: .touchUpInside)" gives me error. It says that I have to replace it with "forControlEvents: .touchUpInside"